# How do I remove a name from my VIP list in Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app

On my Mac mail I have a person listed in my VIP list but I don't even know who the person is. There are no emails in the boxes with his name on it. I cannot find a way to delete this person from my VIP list.

How do I remove this person without removing my VIP folder?

Answer (score 1):

In Mac Mail, under the VIPs Mailbox, control-click the VIP you would like to remove, and select `remove from VIPs`.